# Uninstall for a particular User -Wix 3.5

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

Bonjour,

I have an installer that installs for a per machine , however if i want to uninstall it for a particular user is that possible , since now what i am seeing is that if i am logged in as a standard user and uninstall the msi it asks me for an admin password once i enter and click on continue the installer gets uninstalled for all the users.

Merci.

Emma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is standard behavior, made available starting with Vista, due to the appearance of the UAC. User Account Control support allows any standard user to elevate to an admin account and perform this type of actions, like uninstalling a per-machine installed application.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control

**EDIT**: If you want each user to be able to uninstall the application only for himself than you need to have the installer to installer it separately for each user, i.e. you cannot have an installer that registers the application per-machine and than have users uninstall it separately. Also, if you install the application per-user make sure you are using the correct locations for your resources, like AppData instead of ProgramFiles or HKCU instead of HKLM.

Here are more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/445kc47k.aspx

Comment: Ok that is fine however if i  need an option that if i am logged in as a standard user and uninstalls using the same user account it should be uninstalled for that user only , is that anyhow possible.